# Howto configure apache httpd load balancing with workers that only differ in path, not host?

Tags: load-balancing, apache-2.4

How can load balancing in apache httpd be configured if the workers only differ in path, not host?

E.g. I have the public URL `http://www.example.com/myapp` and this should be load balanced to internal domains `http://internal.domain.com/myapp1` and `http://internal.domain.com/myapp2`(same host, different path)

**Update:** 
Problem is, the following configuration (which I usually use) does not allow different paths on one internal host, it works when every internal host has one context /myapp running.

```
ProxyPass /myapp balancer://workers/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp balancer://workers/myapp

<Proxy balancer://workers>
  BalancerMember http://internal1.domain.com
  BalancerMember http://internal2.domain.com
</Proxy>
```

I found no way to map **/myapp** to

```
internal1.domain.com/myapp1 
internal1.domain.com/myapp2
internal2.domain.com/myapp1
internal2.domain.com/myapp2
```

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to do, or at least not within the scope of what you would normally call a load balancer.  I suspect you'll get more useful answers if you explain a bit more of what this is intended to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would have to run the URLs through `mod_rewrite`. So you'd need to, e.g.,

```
Listen localhost:8180
Listen localhost:8181

<Proxy balancer://workers>
  BalancerMember http://localhost:8180
  BalancerMember http://localhost:8181
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost localhost:8180>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/myapp(.*)$ http://internal.domain.com/myapp1$1 [P]
<VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost:8181>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/myapp(.*)$ http://internal.domain.com/myapp2$1 [P]
<VirtualHost>
```

or something crazy like that.